# Como ordenar por fecha 3 tablas en multi_mysqli

Tags: php, sql

Estoy intentando ordenar por fecha 3 consultas separadas de sql

```
$sql = "SELECT id, category, name, date FROM contactos WHERE id = '$id' ORDER BY date DESC;";
$sql.= "SELECT id, category, name, property, date FROM consultas WHERE id = '$id' ORDER BY date DESC;";
$sql.= "SELECT id, category, area, date FROM propiedades WHERE id = '$id' ORDER BY date DESC;";
```

Hay forma de hacerlo con una sola consulta? SQL?
y que queden ordenadas por fecha?

Actualimente el resultado queda asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero como son por separado y unidos con:

```
foreach ($resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $value) {
```

Entonces no se como ordenarlos las 3 consultas a la vez.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final solucione mi priblema con un `array_multisort`.

Aqui la parte del codigo que me salvo y si alguno necesita ordernar por numero o fecha para un `multi_query`.

```
if ($conn->multi_query($sql)) {
    do {
        if ($result = mysqli_store_result($conn)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $ro[] = $row;
                $date[] = strtotime($row['date']);
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
            array_multisort($ro, SORT_ASC,SORT_NUMERIC,$date, SORT_DESC);
        }
    }
    while (mysqli_next_result($conn));
    foreach ($ro as $row) {
        ......
```

Answer (score 1):

$sql = "SELECT id, category, name, date, 'cadena vacia' FROM contactos WHERE id = '$id'

UNION

SELECT id, category, name, date, property  FROM consultas WHERE id = '$id'

UNION

SELECT id, category, area, date, 'cadena vacia' FROM propiedades WHERE id = '$id'
ORDER BY date DESC;";

ó

$sql = "SELECT id, category, name, date, 'cadena vacia' FROM contactos WHERE id = '$id'

UNION

SELECT id, category, name, date, property  FROM consultas WHERE id = '$id'

UNION

SELECT id, category, area, date, 'cadena vacia' FROM propiedades WHERE id = '$id'
ORDER BY 3 DESC;";

Añadí otro campo a la 1ra y 3ra tabla, llamado "cadena vacia" es para que las 3 tablas llamen a la misma cantidad de columnas, esto es necesario para poder usar UNION.

el order by va al ultimo cuando se usa union, si las 3 tablas tienen un campo que se llama igual, puedes hacerlo a través de ese campo, sino, puedes hacerlo por el numero de columna.

Con UNION se agrupan las filas iguales, si usas UNION ALL, saldrán filas repetidas.

Si quieres que se orden de forma DESC por fecha PERO primero TODOS los registros de la tabla de contactos, despues TODOS los de la tabla consultas y despues TODOS los de la tabla propiedades, solo debes poner parentesis y order by a todos, asi:

$sql = "(SELECT id, category, name, date, 'cadena vacia' FROM contactos WHERE id = '$id'
ORDER BY date DESC)

UNION

(SELECT id, category, name, date, property  FROM consultas WHERE id = '$id'
ORDER BY date DESC)

UNION

(SELECT id, category, area, date, 'cadena vacia' FROM propiedades WHERE id = '$id'
ORDER BY date DESC)";

Comment: Gracias por responder pero no me funciono tu respuesta.

Comment: tenia que haberte funcionado, checa estas paginas a ver si puedes optimizar mas tu codigo, esta es sobre el union: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp y esta es sobre el order by con el union: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html